# 2 Columns Combined Boxplot Where Data Is Grouped By Certain Column

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

My dataset looks like this (for a quick csv file generation, dataset [link](https://pastebin.com/0dZyThPx)):

[image: dataset]

I want grouped boxplots, so here is the simplest implementation I did:

```
fruity = data.boxplot(column=['all', 'taste'], by=['fruit'])
```

Sadly, it gives me separate results, side by side:

[image: separate boxplot]

What I indeed want is something looking like (please ignore the bad editing, but you get the idea):

[image: grouped]

How can this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Let us do `melt`

```
df[['all', 'taste','fruit']].melt('fruit').boxplot(column=['value'], by=['fruit','variable'])
```

Comment: wow, that was fast! any way to make the grouped plots bit more tighter, together?

Comment: @Jishan then you may check the matplot since they have more ability to do customized :-)